# Xamarin.Forms Timer doesn't skip UI logic even when it's not showing?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making a app with using XF PCL.

I started to doubt that XF's timer is not good enough for UI routine. 
for example, in iOS native app, If View is not showing some reason (new page's pushed or something), scheduler is stopped automatically. Because it's for UI.

But Xamarin's doesn't seem like that. 
It's still doing his job.

I hope at least within "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>" will be skipped when it's disappeared.

Am I right? 
Should I put extra logic for that? 
(like stop and restart timer?)
(or declare variable to skip in it?)

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you to unsubscribe to the timer or stop the timer by overriding OnDisappear in the codebehind for the page that is listening. 

I never use the timer , can you refer me to which class are you talking about ?

Comment: @BraveHeart I also think about putting some skipping code from OnDisappear and resume when OnAppearing. Are you asking the timer I use? Device.StartTimer.

Comment: Let's say I want to make stars image and show it every second in my page, I use timer. But It's working continuously even if new page is pushed on navigation and it's hidden.

Comment: well when the page is hidden it is not killed :) I use Prism for navigation and it has a way to navigate and distroy the page . 
But for xamarin navigation i think the way to kill the page is by called PopAsync.
I never used the Timer , i usually use await Task.Delay . but of course if i were you i would put a flag when the page disappears so when the CallBack kicks you could check status of the flag and skip it.

Comment: Thanks @BraveHeart. Remaining page is also another issue of my project. My app is likely Instagram. It's well known app, which can push page endlessly and you can pop every single page. I'm afraid that it will cause memory issue.

Comment: Well then give Prism a try and you will be glad that you used it , it makes your code even much cleaner. 
Do you think I answered your question ? so I can put it as an answer and the question would be considered answerd ?

Comment: @BraveHeart Yes. of course. What is Prism though? I assume that is in nuget gallery and many people downloaded it. Is it like MvvMCross something?

Comment: Yes exactly , I have not used the others though , for me it is familier since I worked shortly with WPF 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYRLcqG2BAY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Andriod usually when you are in **Page1** and then you navigated to **Page2**, although Page1 is hidden it is not killed therefore the worker threads would still working (in that case it is the timer) 
My suggestion is to override the `OnDisappearing` method in the code behind of **Page1** and place the code that would make the timer stop or being ignored. 
If it is for me , I would also place a boolean flag and called `_isPageShown` so when you override `OnDisappearing` and `OnAppearing` you just put the value of `_isPageShown` to false or true accordingly. Then in the callback of the timer you check the flag if it is true or false and act accordingly.